# Обнаружение отдельных объектов на сегментированной маске

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, машинное-обучение, сегментация

У меня есть ЧБ маска, на которой каждый отдельный объект - сегментированная крыша из изображения со спутника. Вся суть задачи - найти каждую ОТДЕЛЬНУЮ крышу, например, представить её в виде списка с координатами.

Так выглядит само изображение (правда, это лишь кусочек, полный вариант больше в 484 раза)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что тут надо найти я так и не понял

Comment: @StrangerintheQ На снимке есть пикселы (строго либо 0, либо 255), многие объединены (большие прямоугольники). Нужно найти каждую группу пикселов.

Comment: получить список белых областей?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ именно, для каждой области найти координаты пикселов, которые ей принадлежат.

Comment: по сути - получить векторное изображение из растрового

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть можно воспользоваться трассировщиком и поучить массив полигонов в векторном формате?

```html
<script src="http://kilobtye.github.io/potrace/potrace.js"></script>
<script>
function process(img) {
  let c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;
  c.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  
  Potrace.loadImageFromUrl(c.toDataURL());
  
  Potrace.process(function(){
    svgdiv.innerHTML = Potrace.getSVG(1);
    let paths = svgdiv.querySelector('path').getAttribute('d').split('M');
    paths.shift();paths.shift();
    svgdiv.querySelector('path').remove();
    svgdiv.querySelector('svg').innerHTML = paths.map(p => {
      return `<path fill=hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,55%) d="M${p}" />`
    });
  });
}
</script>
<img crossOrigin="anonymous" style=display:none  src="https://i.imgur.com/oL3BgBD.png" onload=process(this) />
<div id=svgdiv ></div>
```

Comment: этот же трассировщик(potrace) может окинуть незначительные (малые по площади) области

Comment: По краям пропали некоторые объекты, но думаю, в целом на полном изображении это будет не критичная потеря, или я её вообще смогу её избежать. Спасибо!

Comment: @l4morak не исключено что они попали в границу, которую я удалил (первый полигон), и если что этот алгоритм переписан с плюсовой утилиты(http://potrace.sourceforge.net/), можно ее использовать, вероятно она более продвинутая (я не пробовал)